# XSLT - Group families together

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT 1.0 and I’m looking to divide a xml document of for example related people in to families. The definition of family being one parent and its children.

So this:

```
<person name =”A”>
   <person name =”B”>
      <person name =”D” />
      <person name =”E” />
   </person>
   <person name=”C”>
      <person name =”F” />
      <person name =”G” />
      <person name =”H” />
   </person>
</person>
```

Will result in:

```
<family id =”1”>
   <person name =”A”>
      <person name =”B”/>
      <person name=”C”/>
   </person>
</family>

<family id =”2”>
   <person name =”B”>
      <person name =”D” />
      <person name =”E” />
   </person>
</family>


<family id =”3”>
   <person name=”C”>
      <person name =”F”/>
      <person name =”G”/>
      <person name =”H”/>
   </person>
</family>
```

How can I do this in a simple way?

Comment: Do you require separate XML documents for each "family" or will the output just be one XML document containing all the families (in which case you will need a root element for your output XML)?

Comment: Seperate documets are not required. so I guess I'll need a root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to firstly look for all **person** elements that have other **person** elements as children

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//person[person]"/>
```

Then, for each such **person** element, you would copy the element, and its immediate children only

```
 <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="person" mode="child"/>
 </xsl:copy>
```

Also, to get the family id, you could count all preceding **person** elements, and ancestors

```
<family id="{count(preceding::person[person]) + count(ancestor-or-self::person)}">
```

The "child" template would just copy the **person** and its attributes, but no children.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
       <families>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//person[person]"/>
       </families>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="person[person]">
      <family id="{count(preceding::person[person]) + count(ancestor-or-self::person)}">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person" mode="child"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </family>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="person" mode="child">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<families>
   <family id="1">
      <person name="A">
         <person>B</person>
         <person>C</person>
      </person>
   </family>
   <family id="2">
      <person name="B">
         <person>D</person>
         <person>E</person>
      </person>
   </family>
   <family id="3">
      <person name="C">
         <person>F</person>
         <person>G</person>
         <person>H</person>
      </person>
   </family>
</families>
```

Comment: How would I change it to save the content in the person-tag as attributes? Because they have more than a name. For example: <person firstname="A" lastname="L" phonenumber="0123">
this will output: <person>AL0123</person>
Can I copy each attribute at a time?

Comment: I've corrected the error in my XSLT so it should now copy attributes correctly.

Comment: My only problem now is that the person-tags can be of different types, lets say <boy> or <girl>. But they should be treated the same within the family. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to get this to work.

Comment: Well, do note for future reference, you should always give as much information as you can in the original question. I don't think this new requirement is too hard, but you should probably ask a new question now you have accepted this one.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand what problem fully until I got an answer! So thanks for all your help! :)